# Codeigniter file upload only works on localhost but no on production server

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

My problem is that i made a file upload with codeigniter, and the allowed file types are: DOC, PDF, RTF, DOCX, and its working fine on localhost.

But when im upload it on a production server, no matter what file type im trieing to upload nothing is excepted.

Did anybody else ran into this problem? or can someone give me a hint?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have permission to write to your destination folder in the server (and is it created)? You may look up your apache's `error.log`.

Comment: i cant acces the error log asdly

Comment: probably it is permission issue for read and write

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the production server doesn't recognize your file properly. 
You can try to add

> 'application/octet-stream'

as a new mime type to

> APPPATH/config/mimes.php

for 'doc' and etc.